# When we redirect on standard lead conversion page from LWC then Lead conversion page opened but cancel button is not working ..Any idea?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, lead-conversion

i am overriding standard convert button on lead page so i am calling VF page and from VF page i am calling LWC .

In LWC, I am giving

```
URL(/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole?leadConvert__leadId='+'LeadIDHere')`
```

to redirect to Standard Lead conversion page. Standard Conversion Page is opened but when i click on Cancel button on that Page then Cancel button is not working.Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough info for us to help you here. Please include more details for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: please update your post, instead of adding a long comment